# Gitlab CI variable override in workflow

Tags: gitlab-ci

I want `TEST_VAR` to be overridden by the workflow but when I run a `$NIGHTLY` pipeline, it still prints "normal". What am I doing wrong here? According the the [precedence](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#cicd-variable-precedence), I believe it *should* work...

```
image: alpine

variables:
  TEST_VAR: "normal"

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    - if: $NIGHTLY
      variables:
        TEST_VAR: "nightly"

test:
  script:
    - echo $TEST_VAR
```

Comment: This seems to have been fixed by https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/52085

Answer (score 1):

One more option is hack with child pipelines.

```yaml
nightly-run:
  variables:
    TEST_VAR: "nightly"
  rules:
    - if: $NIGHTLY
  trigger:
    include: .gitlab-ci.yml
    strategy: depend
```

It will override global TEST_VAR if "nightly-run" triggers.

Pay attention all jobs that triggered by "parent pipeline" will with `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'parent_pipeline'`.

Answer (score -1):

A solution can be resolve your issus is to update the $TEST_VAR in script part.

```
script: 
 - |
 - if $NIGHTLY 
   then 
      $TEST_VAR = "nightly"
   else 
      $TEST_VAR = "others values"
   fi
```

Comment: I have about 10 jobs that depend on this variable. This wouldn't be viable on all of them

Comment: so it is better to be in the before_script : https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#before_script

Comment: Same problem, I'd have to put this in every job

Comment: I don't know how you have implement your jobs but normally you can have a default.yml that contain a before_script inclueded in the top for your file jobs.yml     You don't need to add before_script in each jobs.   possible to share a part of your code ?